# Match Table Name and Alias at runtime from DatabaseMetaData?

Tags: java, jdbc, database-metadata

I know how to use `.getTables()` to get the `TABLE` and `ALIAS` entries.

```
final ResultSet rs = dmd.getTables(null, "MySchema", "%", new String[]{"TABLE","ALIAS"});
```

What I need to be able to determine is which `ALIAS` goes with which `TABLE` name?

I specifically need to be able to do this on `Oracle`, `SQL Server` and `DB2`.

And given I have a table `T00001` and it has an alias of `MyTable` how can I match the two up using the `DatabaseMetaData` from a `Connection.getMetaData()` call?

Comment: I don't think it's possible with plain JDBC methods. Any chances you could restrict it to a specific DBMS product? There you usually have more options to look inside the DB schema

Comment: Which DB are you talking about? I am afraid this can't be done in pure JDBC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing the JDBC APIs and [oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseMetaData](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/jdbc/OracleDatabaseMetaData.html), I'm pretty certain that there is no way to retrieve this information directly through [DatabaseMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) when using stock Oracle JDBC drivers.  There may be driver-specific ways for DB2 or SQL Server as I didn't check them out thoroughly.  As a cheat, you can `getConnection()` from the DatabaseMetaData object and run the database-specific queries to retrieve the information you need, as follows:

```
public class TableAliasMapperJdbc {
    public Map<String, List<String>> mapTableAliases(String url, String user, String password, String sql) throws SQLException {
        try (
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            // we use conn.getMetaData().getConnection() instead of conn here only to fit within the parameters of the question
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.getMetaData().getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        ) {
            // this may not do what you want if you have synonyms of synonyms
            Map<String, List<String>> tableAliases = new HashMap<>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                String table = rs.getString(1);
                String alias = rs.getString(2);
                List<String> aliases = tableAliases.get(table);
                if (aliases == null) {
                    tableAliases.put(table, aliases = new ArrayList<>(2));
                }
                aliases.add(alias);
            }
            return tableAliases;
        }
    }

    public void print(String dbName, Map<String, List<String>> tableAliases) {
        System.out.format("\nThe following are the table aliases for %s:\n", dbName);
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : tableAliases.entrySet()) {
            System.out.format("The alias(es) for %s are: %s.\n", entry.getKey(), String.join(", ", entry.getValue()));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        TableAliasMapperJdbc mapper = new TableAliasMapperJdbc();
        mapper.print("Oracle",
            mapper.mapTableAliases(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe",
                "scott",
                "tiger",
                "SELECT table_name, synonym_name FROM user_synonyms")); // or maybe all_synonyms

        mapper.print("DB2",
            mapper.mapTableAliases(
                "jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/SAMPLE",
                "db2admin",
                "db2admin",
                "SELECT base_tabname, tabname FROM syscat.tables WHERE type = 'A' AND owner = 'DB2ADMIN'"));

        mapper.print("SQL Server",
            mapper.mapTableAliases(
                "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433",
                "sa",
                "Password123",
                "SELECT PARSENAME(base_object_name,1), name FROM sys.synonyms"));
    }
}
```

Code was successfully tested using JDK 1.8.0_45, Oracle XE 11.2.0.2.0 and its bundled JDBC driver, DB2 Express-C 10050500 and its bundled JDBC driver, and SQL Server 2014 Express 12.0.2000.8 with Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.1.5605.100.

<sub>SQL Server query based on http://sqlblog.com/blogs/john_paul_cook/archive/2010/08/24/script-to-list-synonym-contents.aspx.</sub>